# How to get the last inserted row with foreach in my blade?

Tags: laravel, foreach

I'm using laravel 5.8 i have two tables **askquestions** and **Responses**. When a user post a 
**question** passing in the front-end, i notify all the back-end agent peer mail with the link they access to the **show.blade.php** here a **button to redirect to the Response Form** but in this form i'm **listing all asked question with a @foreach** but i just want to **show the last asked question**. Need help

---

[image: askQuestions/show.blade.php]

[image: Respones/ControllerRespones.php]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I want to retrieve the last asked question in my blade create responses instead of geting the list of all question

Comment: You should post your code in text, not screenshots.

Comment: you are right !

Answer (score 0):

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route("admin.respones.store") }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 @csrf
<div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('ask_question') ? 'has-error' : '' }}">
<label class="required" for="ask_question_id"><strong>
{{ trans('La question est:') }}</strong></label>
<select class="form-control select2" name="ask_question_id" id="ask_question_id" required>
 @foreach($ask_questions as $id => $ask_question)
 <option value="{{ $id }}" {{ old('ask_question_id') == $id ? 'selected' : '' }}>
{{ $ask_question }}</option>
  @endforeach
  </select>
  @if($errors->has('ask_question_id'))
  <span class="help-block" role="alert">
     {{ $errors->first('ask_question_id') }}
  </span>
  @endif
 <span class="help-block">
 {{ trans('') }}
 </span>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

public function create()
{
    abort_if(Gate::denies('respone_create'), Response::HTTP_FORBIDDEN, '403 Forbidden');

```
$categories = Category::all()->pluck('name', 'id')->prepend(trans('Sélectionnez la thématique'), '');

$author_emails = User::all()->pluck('email', 'id')->prepend(trans('Choisissez votre email'), '');

$ask_questions = AskQuestion::all()->pluck('text_question', 'id');

return view('admin.respones.create', compact('categories', 'author_emails', 'ask_questions'));
```

}